# Embbeding console application inside my application

Tags: c#

I have a console application who start two other console application (not written in C#).

Can I direct the output of the applications to the same CMD window of my application?

Or even just disable them from showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes to both questions - you can redirect the output and also stop them from showing.

Look at the [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class - you pass this into the constructor of the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to ensure it starts just as you want it.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("path to exe to run");

// ensure output is redirected
// several options to read - using the StandardOutput stream of the process
//    another option is to hook up the OutputDataReceived event
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


// ensure no window
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // requires UseShellExecute = false
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You can redirect the output to your calling console application using `RedirectStandardOutput`

### Sample

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"C:\TheOtherApplication.exe"; // Specify exe name.
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

You can also hide the window using ProcessStartInfo's `CreateNoWindow` property.

#### More Information

- [C# RedirectStandardOutput Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput)
- [MSDN - ProcessInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.processinfo.aspx)